# minOccurs attribute in @Group annotation causes UnexpectedRecordException

Tags: spring-boot, bean-io

I am new to Bean-IO and I was trying to configure a validation logic for occurrence of group when a particular record type is available in the file. For example if there are three records in flat file as shown below.

560866
670972
57086659

I am trying to setup the following logic

1. Both 56 and 67 lines together form a multi line record
2. 56&67 records can come independently of record 57,but 57 record cannot come without 56&67.

I was successful in creating the first validation using minOccurs attribute in @record annotation, but was not able to do the same for 56&67 using a group.

Please find the sample code setup below.

HeaderRecord class holds the 56&67 record details

```
@Group
public class HeaderRecord {
    @Record(minOccurs = 1)
    public TX56 tx56;
    @Record(minOccurs = 1)
    public TX67 tx67;
}
```

RecordObject is used to hold the headers and line items

```
public class RecordObject {
@Group(collection = List.class, minOccurs = 1)
    List<HeaderRecord> headerRecords;
    @Record(collection = List.class)
    List<TX57> tx57s;
}

@Record(maxLength = 10, name = "TX56")
public class TX56 {
    @Field(ordinal = 0, at = 0, length = 2, rid = true, literal = "56", trim = true)
    protected int id;
    @Field(ordinal = 1, at = 2, length = 4, trim = true)
    protected int number;
}

@Record(maxLength = 31, name = "TX67")
public class TX67 {
    @Field(ordinal = 0, at = 0, length = 2, rid = true, literal = "67", trim = true)
    protected int id;
    @Field(ordinal = 1, at = 2, length = 4, trim = true)
    protected int number;
}

@Record(maxLength = 71, name = "TX57")
public class TX57 {
    @Field(ordinal = 0, at = 0, length = 2, rid = true, literal = "57", trim = true)
    protected int id;
    @Field(ordinal = 1, at = 2, length = 4, trim = true)
    protected int number;
}
```

with the above configuration when I try to parse the file with records given below, it throws UnexpectedRecordException.
560866
670972
57086659

**Stack trace:**

> 2018-07-17 15:22:07,778[http-nio-8080-exec-2]ERROR
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/].[dispatcherServlet]-Servlet.service()for
>   servlet[dispatcherServlet]in context with path[]threw
>   exception[Request processing failed;nested exception is
>   org.beanio.UnexpectedRecordException:End of stream reached,expected
>   record'tx56']with root cause org.beanio.UnexpectedRecordException:End
>   of stream reached,expected record'tx56' at
>   org.beanio.internal.parser.UnmarshallingContext.newUnsatisfiedRecordException(UnmarshallingContext.java:367)~[beanio-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
>   at
>   org.beanio.internal.parser.Group.unmarshal(Group.java:127)~[beanio-.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
>   at
>   org.beanio.internal.parser.DelegatingParser.unmarshal(DelegatingParser.java:39)~[beanio-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
>   at
>   org.beanio.internal.parser.RecordCollection.unmarshal(RecordCollection.java:42)~[beanio-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
>   at
>   org.beanio.internal.parser.Group.unmarshal(Group.java:118)~[beanio-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
>   at
>   org.beanio.internal.parser.BeanReaderImpl.internalRead(BeanReaderImpl.java:106)~[beanio-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
>   at
>   org.beanio.internal.parser.BeanReaderImpl.read(BeanReaderImpl.java:67)~[beanio-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
>   at
>   dk.coop.integration.fileconversion.service.sampleapplication.createFixedLengthFile(sampleapplication.java:32)~[classes/:?]

Note:
with the above configuration, following scenarios works

- 56&67comes independently
  560866
  670972
- 57cannot come independently
  57086659:this flat file fails with a proper exception
- 56&67should always come as a single record.
  this also works fine.

Additional Details:
Sample Flatfile

560866
670972
560866
670972
560866
670972
57086659
57086659
57086659
57086659
52022
560866
670972
57086659

As seen above, in the flat file there is a possibility that multiple header records and TX57 record can come as a single entity. Also there can be other type of records that can come in between, in which case I have to treat second occurrence of TX56,67 and 57 as a different item.
In the above example first 10 records will form a single recordObject, then the second occurrence of these records will form a second record object. Sorry for not sharing earlier, but there is another wrapper class which holds a list of recordObject.

I am giving the working maven project Github URL below. https://github.com/Jayadeep2308/FlatFileParser

Comment: I have trouble reproducing your problem, I get other errors, which I'm trying to figure out as I go along. I don't know much about using the annotations on BeanIO. Could you perhaps show us how you configure the `StreamFactory` and then how you create the `BeanReader` to read the data from the file.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response and I am updating the question. with all the other relevant details.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**: Updated after all requirements on 5 Aug 2018

I have made all the fields `private` inside the classes and assume that you have the getters + setters in place.

I have tried various combinations of settings on the `@Group` and `@Record` annotations so the code below might not be optimal, but should work.

First the main group (`WrapperObject`) that holds all your data:

```
@Group(minOccurs = 1, maxOccurs = 1)
public class WrapperObject {

  @Group(minOccurs = 0, maxOccurs = 1, collection = List.class)
  private List<RecordObject> recordObjectList;
  @Record(minOccurs = 0, maxOccurs = -1, collection = List.class)
  private List<TX52> tx52s;
}
```

**EDIT**: `RecordObject` updated to hold a list of `HeaderRecord`, also changed the `@Group` values.

```
@Group(minOccurs = 0, maxOccurs = -1)
public class RecordObject {

  @Group(minOccurs = 0, maxOccurs = -1, collection = List.class)
  private List<HeaderRecord> headerRecords;
  @Record(minOccurs = 0, maxOccurs = -1, collection = List.class)
  private List<TX57> tx57s;
}

@Group(minOccurs = 0, maxOccurs = -1)
public class HeaderRecord {

  @Record(minOccurs = 1, maxOccurs = 1)
  private TX56 tx56;
  @Record(minOccurs = 1, maxOccurs = 1)
  private TX67 tx67;
}
```

On the individual TX records I have added the `required=true` attribute on the `@Field` annotation for your record identifier fields.
**Edit**: Added TX52

```
@Record(maxLength = 74, name = "TX52")
public class TX52 {

  @Field(ordinal = 0, at = 0, length = 2, rid = true, literal = "52", trim = true, required = true)
  private int id;
  @Field(ordinal = 1, at = 2, length = 3, trim = true)
  private int number;
}

@Record(maxLength = 10, name = "TX56")
public class TX56 {

  @Field(ordinal = 0, at = 0, length = 2, rid = true, literal = "56", trim = true, required = true)
  private int id;
  @Field(ordinal = 1, at = 2, length = 4, trim = true, required = true)
  private int number;
}

@Record(maxLength = 31, name = "TX67")
public class TX67 {

  @Field(ordinal = 0, at = 0, length = 2, rid = true, literal = "67", trim = true, required = true)
  private int id;
  @Field(ordinal = 1, at = 2, length = 4, trim = true)
  private int number;
}

@Record(maxLength = 71, name = "TX57")
public class TX57 {

  @Field(ordinal = 0, at = 0, length = 2, rid = true, literal = "57", trim = true, required = true)
  private int id;
  @Field(ordinal = 1, at = 2, length = 4, trim = true)
  private int number;
}
```

Lastly, my test code: (**EDIT**: Updated test data)

```
@Test
public void test() {

  final StreamFactory factory = StreamFactory.newInstance();

  final StreamBuilder builder = new StreamBuilder("Jaydeep23")
    .format("fixedlength")
    .parser(new FixedLengthParserBuilder())
    .addGroup(WrapperObject.class);

  factory.define(builder);

  final String scenario1 = "560866\n670972\n560866\n670972\n560866\n670972";
  final String scenario2 = "560866\n670972\n560866\n670972\n560866\n670972\n57086659\n57086659\n57086659\n" +
  "57086659\n560866\n670972\n57086659\n560866\n670972";
  // invalid
  final String scenario3 = "57086659\n57086659\n57086659\n57086659\n57086659";
  final String scenario4 = "52022\n52066\n52054\n52120";
  final String scenario5 = scenario1;
  final String scenario6 = "560866\n670972\n560866\n670972\n560866\n670972\n57086659\n57086659\n57086659\n" +
  "57086659\n52021\n52022\n52023\n560866\n670972\n57086659\n52023";

  final String message = scenario1;
  BeanReader beanReader = null;
  Object object = null;
  try (final Reader in = new BufferedReader(new StringReader(message))) {
    beanReader = factory.createReader("Jaydeep23", in);
    beanReader.setErrorHandler(new LoggingBeanReaderErrorHandler());
    while ((object = beanReader.read()) != null) {
      System.out.println("Object = " + object);
    }
  } catch (final Exception e) {
    fail(e.getMessage());
  } finally {
    if (beanReader != null) {
      beanReader.close();
    }
  }
}
```

Generates this output: (**EDIT**: using your `toString()` methods)

```
Scenario 1 = [[Record Type = 56, Store Number = 866
Record Type = 67, Store Number = 972
, Record Type = 56, Store Number = 866
Record Type = 67, Store Number = 972
, Record Type = 56, Store Number = 866
Record Type = 67, Store Number = 972
]null]null

Scenario 2 = [[Record Type = 56, Store Number = 866
Record Type = 67, Store Number = 972
, Record Type = 56, Store Number = 866
Record Type = 67, Store Number = 972
, Record Type = 56, Store Number = 866
Record Type = 67, Store Number = 972
, Record Type = 56, Store Number = 866
Record Type = 67, Store Number = 972
, Record Type = 56, Store Number = 866
Record Type = 67, Store Number = 972
][Record Type = 57, Store Number = 866
, Record Type = 57, Store Number = 866
, Record Type = 57, Store Number = 866
, Record Type = 57, Store Number = 866
, Record Type = 57, Store Number = 866
]]null

Scenario 3 - gives this error (which is correct according as TX57 is not allowed on its own:
Expected record/group 'tx56' at line 6

Scenario 4 = null[Record Type = 52, Store Number = 22
, Record Type = 52, Store Number = 66
, Record Type = 52, Store Number = 54
, Record Type = 52, Store Number = 120
]

Scenario 5 = [[Record Type = 56, Store Number = 866
Record Type = 67, Store Number = 972
, Record Type = 56, Store Number = 866
Record Type = 67, Store Number = 972
, Record Type = 56, Store Number = 866
Record Type = 67, Store Number = 972
]null]null

Scenario 6 = [[Record Type = 56, Store Number = 866
Record Type = 67, Store Number = 972
, Record Type = 56, Store Number = 866
Record Type = 67, Store Number = 972
, Record Type = 56, Store Number = 866
Record Type = 67, Store Number = 972
][Record Type = 57, Store Number = 866
, Record Type = 57, Store Number = 866
, Record Type = 57, Store Number = 866
, Record Type = 57, Store Number = 866
]][Record Type = 52, Store Number = 21
, Record Type = 52, Store Number = 22
, Record Type = 52, Store Number = 23
]
```

Hope this helps.

Let me know if it is now working for you.

Comment: Hi, Thank you very much for the response. The reason I have the headerRecord as a list is because there is a possibility that in a single set there can be multiple records. I have updated the question to reflect a sample working model of my actual requirement. I got it working for a single header, but I was looking at how it can work with a list of Header record. When you run the git Project, please updated the file location in the service class. I didn't have time to load the file In a nicer way than that(Chose not to use resource loader, since it requires restart on file change).

Comment: I have updated my answer to reflect the changes in your question

Comment: Hi, I have two quick questions, could you please share me your RecordObject class. Also I think that the StreamBuilder builder object should add the WrapperClass group rather than the RecordObject, Am I wrong?

Comment: I have added the `RecordObject` to the answer, sorry, it got lost in the previous update. Yes, you are correct, the `WrapperObject` should be added to the `StreamBuilder`. It is now fixed in my answer as well.

Comment: Hi Nicoschl, Thank you for the quick reply. But your code enforces RecordObject to be available at least once in the file. But my requirement is to have the HeaderObject at lease once if TX57 comes in flat file. But there can also be files which can have only TX52 records. That's why I was trying to enforce minOccurs on the headerRecords variable, but not on the RecordObject class itself.

Comment: Just an addition, Please find the different scenarios for the flat file.
1. Just 56 &67 records - Valid.
2. 56 ,67 & 57 records - valid.
3. just 57 records - invalid(56&67 should be accompanied with 57).
4. just 52 records -  valid.
5. list of 56 & 57 - valid.
6. combination of 56,67 & 57 and 52 records - valid
Also other requirements is that 56 & 67 should always come together.

Comment: Hi @Nicoschl, were you able to look into my comments

Comment: I'm a little busy with a project at the moment, will look at it when I get a chance

Comment: No problem I understand :)